# constant function in the limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a sequence of functions $u_i=u_i(x)$ such that

$u_i-c_i \rightarrow v$ locally uniformly in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$,

where $c_i$ is a sequence of numbers. Moreover, I know that $|\nabla u_i| \leq \frac{C}{|x|}$, $C$ is a constant.

Is this enough to say to in the limit, $v$ is not constant ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain well. $u = u_i$ is a sequence of function and so is $c=c_i$, a sequence of numbers. I will change this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't say anything abouth the constantness of $v$.

$v$ could be constant if you set $u_i(x) = 0$ and $c_i=0$, then you have that $v(x)=0$.

You could also have that $u_i(x) = e^{-|x|^2}$ and $c_i = 0$ then $v(x) = e^{-|x|^2}$ which is not constant.